# Will I be refused travel due to my flight ticket having a space in my first name?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

My **first name** is SmithQi on the passport, but my ticket shows Smith Qi. Will I be refused travel due to my flight ticket not having space in my first name?

Comment: Did you mean that your passport has the space, but the ticket does not?

Comment: no, my name is SmithQi Sun on the passport but my name on the ticket is Smith Qi Sun.

Comment: Your question title and question body contradict each other: the title says your ticket does not have a space; the body says it does. I read the title and answered the wrong question. Thankfully, somebody noticed.

Answer (score 3):

There was a case for my friend's passport where the name didn't exactly match the passport name.

She was not able to use automated counter for collecting boarding pass. But the counter happily issued a boarding pass (after a long queue). Just arrive earlier than usual for the possible things like that and you will be fine. Airport staff is human, they can understand that its indeed you.

Airport - Changi Airport, Singapore

Answer (score 1):

No!

I have experienced the same problem, since I have multiple last names.

Sometimes the ticket has only the last last name, or when buying from third parties everything is joined together without whitespaces.
In your case, there is an extra whitespace in your ticket. It is the same problem as mine, but the other way around.

While you may need to go directly to the counter, these situations do not present an identity verification problem, and they should issue your ticket normally.